# Remove consecutive duplicate elements in-place in Rust

Tags: vector, rust

I have the following python function that removes consecutive duplicated numbers **in-place** (meaning `[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]` becomes `[0, 1, 2, 3]`):

```py
def del_consec_dupl(nums: List[int]):
    for (idx, n) in enumerate(nums):
        while idx < len(nums) - 1 and n == nums[idx + 1]:
            del nums[idx]
```

it needs to be rewritten in Rust while respecting the constraint that it must work in-place without allocating an extra vector/array. When trying to literally translating this:

```rust
fn del_consec_dupl(nums: &mut Vec<i32>) {
    for (idx, n) in nums.iter().enumerate() {
        while idx < nums.len() - 1 && *n == nums[idx + 1] {
            nums.remove(idx);
        }
    }
}
```

will produce the following errors:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*nums` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
 --> src/main.rs:4:21
  |
3 |     for (idx, n) in nums.iter_mut().enumerate() {
  |                     ---------------------------
  |                     |
  |                     mutable borrow occurs here
  |                     mutable borrow later used here
4 |         while idx < nums.len() - 1 && *n == nums[idx + 1] {
  |                     ^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here

error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*nums` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
 --> src/main.rs:4:45
  |
3 |     for (idx, n) in nums.iter_mut().enumerate() {
  |                     ---------------------------
  |                     |
  |                     mutable borrow occurs here
  |                     mutable borrow later used here
4 |         while idx < nums.len() - 1 && *n == nums[idx + 1] {
  |                                             ^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here

error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*nums` as mutable more than once at a time
 --> src/main.rs:5:13
  |
3 |     for (idx, n) in nums.iter_mut().enumerate() {
  |                     ---------------------------
  |                     |
  |                     first mutable borrow occurs here
  |                     first borrow later used here
4 |         while idx < nums.len() - 1 && *n == nums[idx + 1] {
5 |             nums.remove(idx);
  |             ^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here

error: aborting due to 3 previous errors
```

it seems no matter what I do, I can only solve 2 of 3. It seems the main issue here is trying to refer to the length of the vector while it is being mutated inside the iteration.

Would I need an `unsafe` block here? or how would you go about solving it?

Answer (score 4):

I would not use `remove` which moves all the elements after the given index and is inefficient, but just overwrite elements in the same array, dealing with the double-borrow problem by using indexes:

```rust
fn del_consec_dupl(nums: &mut Vec<i32>) {
    let mut di = 0; // "destination" increment
    for si in 1..nums.len() { // increment on the "source"
        if nums[si] != nums[si-1] {
            di += 1;
            nums[di] = nums[si];
        }
    }
    nums.truncate(di+1); // cut off the tail
}
```

There's no need to use `unsafe` here.

Answer (score 4):

Rust vectors provide the built-in [`dedup()` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.dedup) which does exactly what you are asking for, so the easiest way to write your code is `nums.dedup();`.

For integers, or more generally `Copy` types, you can also implement the same functionality using the `retain()` method:

```
fn retain_uniq<T: Copy + PartialEq>(nums: &mut Vec<T>) {
    let mut previous = None;
    nums.retain(|&x| Some(x) != std::mem::replace(&mut previous, Some(x)))
}
```